# Chromosomally different D. melanogaster sperm

Tags: genetics

I know that *D. melanogaster* have 4 pairs of chromosomes and crossing over is absent in males. Denoting autosomes as *Ai,j* where i is chromosome no. and j are homologues (1 and 2) I am solving the total no. of chromosomally different sperm as 8. I am assuming it as 2x2x2. Can anyone verify my answer?